# CS231n: How to calculate gradient for Softmax loss function?

Tags: python, numpy, softmax

I am watching some videos for Stanford CS231: Convolutional Neural Networks for Visual Recognition but do not quite understand how to calculate analytical gradient for softmax loss function using `numpy`.

From [this stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/945871/derivative-of-softmax-loss-function) answer, softmax gradient is calculated as:

[image: derivative calculation]

Python implementation for above is:

```
num_classes = W.shape[0]
num_train = X.shape[1]
for i in range(num_train):
  for j in range(num_classes):
    p = np.exp(f_i[j])/sum_i
    dW[j, :] += (p-(j == y[i])) * X[:, i]
```

Could anyone explain how the above snippet work? Detailed implementation for softmax is also included below.

```
def softmax_loss_naive(W, X, y, reg):
  """
  Softmax loss function, naive implementation (with loops)
  Inputs:
  - W: C x D array of weights
  - X: D x N array of data. Data are D-dimensional columns
  - y: 1-dimensional array of length N with labels 0...K-1, for K classes
  - reg: (float) regularization strength
  Returns:
  a tuple of:
  - loss as single float
  - gradient with respect to weights W, an array of same size as W
  """
  # Initialize the loss and gradient to zero.
  loss = 0.0
  dW = np.zeros_like(W)

  #############################################################################
  # Compute the softmax loss and its gradient using explicit loops.           #
  # Store the loss in loss and the gradient in dW. If you are not careful     #
  # here, it is easy to run into numeric instability. Don't forget the        #
  # regularization!                                                           #
  #############################################################################

  # Get shapes
  num_classes = W.shape[0]
  num_train = X.shape[1]

  for i in range(num_train):
    # Compute vector of scores
    f_i = W.dot(X[:, i]) # in R^{num_classes}

    # Normalization trick to avoid numerical instability, per http://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/#softmax
    log_c = np.max(f_i)
    f_i -= log_c

    # Compute loss (and add to it, divided later)
    # L_i = - f(x_i)_{y_i} + log \sum_j e^{f(x_i)_j}
    sum_i = 0.0
    for f_i_j in f_i:
      sum_i += np.exp(f_i_j)
    loss += -f_i[y[i]] + np.log(sum_i)

    # Compute gradient
    # dw_j = 1/num_train * \sum_i[x_i * (p(y_i = j)-Ind{y_i = j} )]
    # Here we are computing the contribution to the inner sum for a given i.
    for j in range(num_classes):
      p = np.exp(f_i[j])/sum_i
      dW[j, :] += (p-(j == y[i])) * X[:, i]

  # Compute average
  loss /= num_train
  dW /= num_train

  # Regularization
  loss += 0.5 * reg * np.sum(W * W)
  dW += reg*W

  return loss, dW
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but:

[image: y_i] is really the indicator function [image: y_i], as described [here](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Softmax_Regression#Cost_Function). This forms the expression `(j == y[i])` in the code.

Also, the gradient of the loss with respect to the weights is:

[image: y_i]

where

[image: y_i]

which is the origin of the `X[:,i]` in the code.

Comment: Thank for pointing that out. I didn't see it in first place. In the question on stackexchange, they implicitly denote yj for for the indicator function

Comment: And,the value of the first term(dL/df) in the gradient is:  y_pred-y.

Answer (score 12):

I know this is late but here's my answer:

I'm assuming you are familiar with the cs231n Softmax loss function. 
We know that:
[image]

So just as we did with the SVM loss function the gradients are as follows:
[image]

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 5):

A [supplement to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972798/4233113) with a small example.

[image: calculation]

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post and still was not 100% clear how to arrive at the partial derivatives.

For that reason I took another approach to get to the same results - maybe it is helpful to others too.

[image]