# Numerical computation of softmax cross entropy gradient

Tags: python, numpy, softmax

I implemented the `softmax()` function, `softmax_crossentropy()` and the derivative of softmax cross entropy: `grad_softmax_crossentropy()`. Now I wanted to compute the derivative of the softmax cross entropy function numerically. I tried to do this by using the finite difference method but the function returns only zeros. Here is my code with some random data:

```
import numpy as np

batch_size = 3
classes = 10

# random preactivations
a = np.random.randint(1,100,(batch_size,classes))
# random labels
y = np.random.randint(0,np.size(a,axis=1),(batch_size,1))

def softmax(a):
    epowa = np.exp(a-np.max(a,axis=1,keepdims=True))
    return epowa/np.sum(epowa,axis=1,keepdims=True)

print(softmax(a))

def softmax_crossentropy(a, y):
    y_one_hot = np.eye(classes)[y[:,0]]
    return -np.sum(y_one_hot*np.log(softmax(a)),axis=1)

print(softmax_crossentropy(a, y))

def grad_softmax_crossentropy(a, y):
    y_one_hot = np.eye(classes)[y[:,0]]
    return softmax(a) - y_one_hot

print(grad_softmax_crossentropy(a, y))

# Finite difference approach to compute grad_softmax_crossentropy()
eps = 1e-5
print((softmax_crossentropy(a+eps,y)-softmax_crossentropy(a,y))/eps)
```

What did I wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CS231n: How to calculate gradient for Softmax loss function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663874/cs231n-how-to-calculate-gradient-for-softmax-loss-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could do it. I think you're referring to the gradient wrt the activations indicated by y's indicator matrix.

First, I instantiate `a` as `float` to change individual items.

```
a = np.random.randint(1,100,(batch_size,classes)).astype("float")
```

Then,

```
np.diag(grad_softmax_crossentropy(a, y)[:, y.flatten()])

array([ -1.00000000e+00,  -1.00000000e+00,  -4.28339542e-04])
```

But also

```
b = a.copy()
for i, o in zip(y.max(axis=1), range(y.shape[0])):
    b[o, i] += eps

(softmax_crossentropy(b,y)-softmax_crossentropy(a,y))/eps
[ -1.00000000e+00  -1.00000000e+00  -4.28125536e-04]
```

So basically you have to change a_i in softmax, not the entirety of a.